# When load too much asset images App will crash

Tags: dart, flutter, assets, flutter-dependencies

I run this application on Android 9 device. First time `flutter run` application working well. But when Uninstall and `flutter run` this error is coming and application crash..I load 500svg images and 3 json file in asset folder. Is that other way to add asset or how to fix this?

```
Error writing "build/flutter_assets/assets/images/Defect/icon-96.svg" to DevFS: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:59192/-ontPA9YbJc=/
```

> ```
>   assets:
>   - assets/images/
>   - assets/images/Register/
>   - assets/images/Defect/
>   - assets/locale/localization_en.json
>   - assets/locale/localization_es.json
>   - assets/locale/localization_fr.json
> ```

Comment: why do you want to load 500 images at once? cannot you load them on demand? i cannot imagine you need 500 images on one screen

Comment: Could it be some remove assets on uninstall flag that you have missed.

Comment: no sir. I am not loading 500 images once. example id name is icon-01.svg. this icon loading in my listView. `if id == 01` then loading this image... This error will happen only when unistall app and reinstall. after open application app will crash

Comment: @HarounHajem how to remove assets on unistall?

Comment: They should be uninstalled, I've read a little bit more. But if you put the files in some other cache that could be an issue.

Comment: No I didn't not cache svg. I user flutter_svg plugin for load